# Customize scrolling in Android TV

Tags: android, android-scrollview, android-tv

I need to a TV application with UI like this:

[image: UI prototype]

When pressing up/down button on the remote video info should be collapsed, then the grid should scroll, and after that the new video info should expand.

Each line is loaded separately and have its own pagination.

I implemented it with `ScrollView` with `RecyclerViews` inside. But animations are not smooth, as `ScrollView` scrolls a little first, and then my custom animations are started. I'd like to suppress scrolls on up/down buttons click and handle them by manually. I made a `ScrollView` descendant and tried to override something for this.

```
public class VideoSelector extends ScrollView {
    public VideoSelector(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        return true;

    }

    @Override
    public boolean canScrollVertically(int direction) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        DPLog.i("ScrollView onTouchEvent: %s", event.toString());
        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        DPLog.i("ScrollView key down: %s", event.toString());
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        DPLog.i("ScrollView key up: %s", event.toString());
        return super.onKeyUp(keyCode, event);
    }
 }
```

That doesn't work, `onKeyUp` or `onKeyDown` are never called.

The only way I found to catch key events is to override `onKeyDown` in `Activity`. This function is called fine. But it seems to be an ugly solution. 
What else can I do to handle key events from the remote in views in TV app?

May be it's possible to make such UI with leanback controls?

Comment: Did you find the solution ? I am having a similar problem, if you can help. https://stackoverflow.com/q/67972525/4732846

Answer (score 0):

You can try using ObersvableScrollView. Set the callback listener (as mentioned below), on onScrollChanged() - update UI. Also, on onKeyDown event of your activity, you can scroll the observalbeScrollView to desired y position ex. **observableScrollView.scrollVerticallyTo(100)**

```
observableScrollView.setScrollViewCallbacks(new ObservableScrollViewCallbacks() {
                @Override
                public void onScrollChanged(int scrollY, boolean firstScroll, boolean dragging) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onDownMotionEvent() {

                }

                @Override
                public void onUpOrCancelMotionEvent(ScrollState scrollState) {

                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use BrowseFragment component of leanback API. There are some callback method like onItemSelected() you can get the position and data for selected item them you can easily show the info hover.