# Focus not moving out of RowsSupportFragment

Tags: android, android-layout, android-tv, leanback

I have created an activity which has simple button and a RowsSupportFragment placed at bottom.

Initial focus is given to Button and when I press D-pad down focus shifts to item in RowsSupportFragment and after which only D-pad right and D-pad left works, when I click up D-pad up the focus doesn't go to the button.

[image]

activity_test.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".standard.TestActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnTest"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Test"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragmentContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="220dp"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

TestActivity.kt

```
class TestActivity : FragmentActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_test)
        loadFragment()
    }

    private fun loadFragment() {
        supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, BingeRowFragment())
            .commit()
    }
}
```

BingeRowFragment.kt

```
class BingeRowFragment : RowsSupportFragment() {

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        createRows()
    }

    private fun createRows() {
        val movieList = listOf("Movie1", "Movie2", "Movie3", "Movie4", "Movie5", "Movie6",
            "Movie7", "Movie8", "Movie9", "Movie10", "Movie11", "Movie12")

        val itemPresenter = BingeItemPresenter()
        val listRowAdapter = ArrayObjectAdapter(itemPresenter)
        movieList.forEach {
            listRowAdapter.add(it)
        }

        val rowsAdapter = ArrayObjectAdapter(ListRowPresenter(FocusHighlight.ZOOM_FACTOR_MEDIUM))
        rowsAdapter.add(ListRow(listRowAdapter))
        adapter = rowsAdapter
    }
}
```

BingeItemPresenter.kt

```
class BingeItemPresenter: Presenter() {

    private lateinit var movieImage: ImageView
    private lateinit var movieTitle: TextView

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup): ViewHolder {
        // margin between items
        parent.findViewById<HorizontalGridView>(R.id.row_content).setItemSpacing(24)
        val cardViewLayout = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
            .inflate(R.layout.standard_movie_item, parent, false)

        movieImage = cardViewLayout.findViewById(R.id.movie_image)
        movieTitle = cardViewLayout.findViewById(R.id.movie_name)

        return ViewHolder(cardViewLayout)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(viewHolder: ViewHolder, item: Any) {
        val movie = item as String
        movieImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.movie)
        movieTitle.text = movie
    }

    override fun onUnbindViewHolder(viewHolder: ViewHolder?) {
        // nullify image
    }
}
```

Comment: Please share your layout and the code

Comment: I made a silly mistake, the style I was using was not of leanback, rather AppCompat, <style name="AppTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar" /> , changing it to parent="@style/Theme.Leanback", worked fine.

Comment: I am facing something similar. Wanted to know if this is only happening on API 28?

Comment: @SubhasmithThapa, for me it is not specific to os. Sometimes you might miss to notice the focus, add some highlighter to the view in focused state.

Comment: I have posted a solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58333794/how-to-move-focus-from-rowssupportfragments-row-to-next-layout-component/77346536#77346536

Answer (score 1):

Try adding

```
 <item name="focusOutFront">true</item>
 <item name="focusOutEnd">true</item>
```

to the VerticalGridView styles in `styles.xml`

If it doesn't work, try adding

```
app:focusOutEnd="true"
app:focusOutFront="true"
```

to the VerticalGridView in `lb_rows_fragment.xml`

Comment: I made a silly mistake, the style I was using was not of leanback, rather AppCompat, <style name="AppTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar" /> , changing it to parent="@style/Theme.Leanback", worked fine.